# Allow surrogate to update question

Tags: discussion

I just tested this premise here https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11379638

The reject reason, 3 votes to 2, was "This edit was intended to address the author of the post ...."

Not so, the author has abandoned the question. The intent was to add information as though I was the author to update the people answering, as an OP might have done. The text was too much to go into a comment. This is possibly a new concept to many, if not all.

Comment: Where did that extra-info come from? It was completely your own invention, taking over the question. As such, clearly conflicts with author's intent might look better as a rejection reason, but rejected it would be.

Comment: I edited your meta question to remove the meta meta-voting suggestions.  Now voters can vote for the normal reasons (like research, clarity, and general agreement).

Comment: "_as though I was the author_" exactly.  Thus conflict's with the author's intent (another related rejection reason).

Comment: You're not supposed to "update the people answering". You seem to have missed the point of the site.

Comment: I can't believe 2 people approved this.  In this case, if this information was helpful, you should post your solution (including test data) in an answer.

Comment: @BrendanAbel I do not have a solution other people tried to provide a solution to me.

Answer (score 18):

That was an inappropriate edit and was rightly rejected. The two reviewers who approved that were mistaken, and I've acted on that as well.

Edits can improve and clarify a question, but must preserve its intent. Your edit was a response to one of the answers, not a clarification of the question. It put words in the asker's mouth, and wouldn't have been a good update to the question even if they had edited it in this manner.

If you have a new question to ask that is based on one of the existing answers, or that builds upon this question, ask that new question and refer back to this one. If an answer is incorrect or unclear, leave a comment on that answer indicating this. A suggested edit that adds a response into someone else's question should be rejected by reviewers.